# How can I calculate the average of multiple beta coefficients from a rolling window?

Tags: sas, average, regression

I'm a beginner to SAS  (and stackexchange) and would really appreciate some assistance.

I currently have a regression setup in SAS which is a basic macro that runs the same single variable OLS model each year, using the prior 20 observations. That is, the year 1952 uses data from 1933 to 1952, and yields a beta for that period, with associated errors.

My goal is to calculate an average of these coefficients each decade, but I want to take into account the errors associated with each regression coefficient. Then for each decade i'd like to test whether the betas for the rolling window over that decade are significantly different from zero.

I currently have one large dataset which simply lists standard error, pvalue, beta and date, for every period. Below is a worked example of my simple code

```
%MACRO A_ROLLING (i);   
proc reg data=dataset
outest=temp_dataset (drop=_model_) tableout;
model y = x / NOINT;
WHERE t >(1+&i) and t <(22+&i);
run;

data A_EQ1ROLLING;
set A_EQ1ROLLING temp_dataset;
run;
%mend

DATA A_EQ1ROLLING; 
RUN;
%MACRO A_ROLL;
%do j=0 %to 64;
    %A_ROLLING (&j);
%end; 
%MEND;

%A_ROLL;
```

Comment: Do you have SAS/ETS licenced?  If so, moving averages are easily calculated using `proc expand`.

Comment: If you don't have ETS, SAS has example code of how to calculate a moving average using the data step.  http://support.sas.com/kb/25/027.html